# Create and Edit lookup items contained within an item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have an item that, among its other fields, contains a variable number (0-20, if it's of any consequence) of items that themselves have 3 fields (Year, Number, Number). These "inner" items (akin to previous years' performances) do not make sense to edit on their own, outside of the context of the outer item's details.

In attempting to allow these fields to have these multiple values, I've found that only lookup and person/group items may have 'multiple values'. I have been able to make a list for the inner items to reside in, and am able to select these items using a lookup field I've created. However, creating the items in a separate form is inadequate for my use case, and furthermore, having to select them from a list of all the other items' previous years' performances is a giant mess.

Is there a SPD/InfoPath/JavaScript solution for creating and editing these inner items from within a form for the outer item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you are after a parent/child relationship (or multiple relationships) between lists.

You can edit the parent's list form to include a view of child items and create new child items for the parent from within that form. All you need is SharePoint Designer to edit the parent list form and some javascript to pre-populate the child's key ID.

A complete tutorial with videos can be found at [The SharePoint Hillbilly](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2010/12/16/creating-a-sharepoint-parentchild-list-relationshipndash-sharepoint-2010-edition.aspx) blog.

Alternatively, you could use InfoPath. A list form will not support that kind of functionality, but a browser form can. It will require code to manage writing to the different lists, or you can buy 3rd party tools like Qdabra's qRules that have all the code already in place.